# Datetime format with time zones

Tags: mysql, datetime, timezone

I am pulling date from API as a string in this format: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'`

The problem is when I try to save it, let's say today `2015-01-23T13:42:00Z` the flags `Z` and `T` are not shown in MySQL database (the date is saved like this `2015-01-23 13:42:00`).

I would like to keep the field date type, i.e. I don't want to save the date into `varchar` field.

I am not familiar with date timezone format, so any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: `2015-01-23T13:42:00Z` seems like an error to me. It closely resembles ISO8601 or RFC3339 format (`2015-01-23T13:42:00+0000` or `2015-01-23T13:42:00+00:00` respectively) other then that `Z` 'flag'.

Comment: Generally speaking, you should first convert your dates to UTC timezone, before you store them. Then, when you retrieve them, you convert them to user timezone.

Comment: @chromice `Z` is allowed by both ISO8601 and RFC3339.  It means explicitly UTC, whereas +00:00 might be UTC, or might be from a time zone that just happens to be aligned with UTC at that moment (like UK in the winter).  There's no error here, and it is quite common.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, read about the `DATETIME`, and `TIMESTAMP` types [in the mysql docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html).

Then, make a decision on which field type to use:

- If you want to submit, store, and retrieve the same value without ever having MySQL perform time zone conversions, then use a `DATETIME` field.
- If you want to submit and retrieve values to/from the field using a specific time zone, but actually store a UTC time, then use `TIMESTAMP`.

  - Consider that you might want to still use a `TIMESTAMP` type for UTC-based values, but just set the session time zone explicitly to UTC.
- Never *ever* store date/time values in a `VARCHAR` field.

Finally, realize that there's a huge difference between what is actually *stored* in the database, versus what you *see* when you examine the data. The database is storing things efficiently, in a non-visible binary representation.  You simply *observe* that value projected to a specific format during display.  The format you use when you submit the data helps to craft the binary value, but then those strings are discarded.  Later when you look at the field, if you print them to the screen then it converts back to a string so it can show you the value.

It's no different then if you sent an integer as "1,234" - it doesn't actually store that string, it stores `0x04D2` (or `0000 0100 1101 0010` in binary).  You could read that back as "1234" or "1,234" and the *formatting* of putting the comma in the right place has nothing whatsoever to do with how the value was stored.  It only has to do with how the tool that shows you the value renders it for output.  The same thing is going on with your date formatting scenario.

Comment: Well explained. Thank you @Matt

Comment: How to convert RFC3339 string (with nanoseconds) [e.g., `2024-03-11T16:10:23.123456789-04:00`] into DATETIME for MySQL?